# Is a cursor parameter really to be declared differently than a "regular" parameter?

Tags: c#, oracle, devart, dotconnect

OK, nobody seems to know how to solve the problem I'm having looping through a cursor/result set for storage into a List, so I'm going to break it down into pieces and try to slog through it that way. So, first of all:

I add SQL Parameters to an OracleCommand object this way (works fine):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("ABCID", _ABCID);
cmd.Parameters["ABCID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmd.Parameters["ABCID"].DbType = DbType.String;
```

IOW, when I add the param, I pass the name of the parameterized portion of the SQL ("ABCID" above) and a value to give it (_ABCID is a variable that has been assigned, let's say, "42").

However, when adding a Cursor (output) param, it seems to want, not a value (such as an initialized cursor object), but simply the data type:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("cur", Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleDbType.Cursor);
cmd.Parameters["cur"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

(I tried both ways, and neither one works, so...?)

Verily/thus, my question is: Is this really the correct way of declaring a Cursor parameter to be outputted back for traversal/access?

I'm using the brand new version of DevArt DotConnect components (6.80.332), VS 2010, .NET 4

Updated:

Here's the code in more context:

```
public void PopulateCurrentUserRoles(String AUserName, List<String> ACurrentUserRoles) { 
  _UserName = AUserName; 

  String query = "select roleid from ABCrole where ABCid = :ABCID"; 
  Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleCommand cmd = new Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleCommand(query, con); 
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
  int _ABCID = GetABCIDForUserName(); 

  cmd.Parameters.Add("cur", Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleDbType.Cursor); 
  cmd.Parameters["cur"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 

  cmd.Parameters.Add("ABCID", _ABCID); 
  cmd.Parameters["ABCID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input; 
  cmd.Parameters["ABCID"].DbType = DbType.String; 
  //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); blows up: "illegal variable name/number" 
  //cmd.ExecuteCursor();   " " 
  //cmd.ExecuteReader();   " " 
  Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleCursor oraCursor = 
    (Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleCursor)cmd.Parameters["cur"].Value; 
  Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleDataReader odr = oraCursor.GetDataReader(); // "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" 
  while (odr.Read()) { 
    ACurrentUserRoles.Add(odr.GetString(0)); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a cursor? Cursors are (generally) the worst thing you can do in SQL? I suggest relooking at the SQL AND/OR using a WHILE loop. Remember, SQL is SET based logic, not procedural. If you are looping heavily, then you should be doing this in your code, not the SQL

Comment: "neither one works" doesn't really explain what you've observed when you've tried it...

Comment: @Jon: If I call ExecuteNonQuery() - which seems to be the consensus, although it makes no sense to me, as my SQL statements IS a query (Select) - I get, "illegal variable name/number".

If I comment ExecuteNonQuery() out, I get, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when I call GetDataReader()

Comment: @Justin: I'm trying to use a while loop, and that's what I was doing with Oracle's ODP components. I'm not seeing how to do it with the DotConnect components.

Comment: @Justin: My SQL is a simple select with a parameter. I want to loop through the result set, assigning what the SQL returns to the members of a List of String.

Comment: @ClayShannon: You haven't shown the code which is calling `GetDataReader`, which makes it hard to say what's going on...

Comment: I'll add the code above in an "Updated" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight from the horse's mouth (the DevArt folks):

```
_UserName = AUserName;
// From the DevArtisans:
String query = "select roleid from ABCrole where ABCid = :ABCID";
Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleCommand cmd = new Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleCommand(query, con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
int _ABCID = GetABCIDForUserName();
cmd.Parameters.Add("ABCID", _ABCID);
cmd.Parameters["ABCID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmd.Parameters["ABCID"].DbType = DbType.String;
Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleDataReader odr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (odr.Read()) {
  ACurrentUserRoles.Add(odr.GetString(0));
}
```

To quote Casey and the Sonshine Banned, "That's the way, Uh huh Uh huh, I like it, Uh huh Uh huh"; actually, I can't stand that crap, but I do kind of relate to that sentiment right about now.

Answer (score 1):

the following is from the *Oracle Data Provider for .NET Developer's Guide*. yes, I know, "Devart". Nonetheless, It suggests the following:

- Be careful with your parameter typing declaration.
- add that cursor/output parameter to the Parameters collection before
  any others.

As a long shot... my guide shows a `OracleDbType.RefCursor` but not a `OracleDbType.Cursor`. If DevArt has RefCursor, try that. In visual studio, what type does .NET think that parameter is? This question is not as dumb as I used to think.

> ... On the other hand, if the parameter is set as an OracleDbType.Char type by setting the OracleDbType property, the output data is returned
>   as an OracleString type. If both DbType and OracleDbType properties
>   are set before the command execution, the last setting takes affect.
>
> . . .
>
> "An application should not bind a value for output parameters; it is
>   the responsibility of ODP.NET to create the value object and populate
>   the OracleParameter Value property with the object. When binding by
>   position (default) to a function, ODP.NET expects the return value to
>   be bound first, before any other parameters."

---

**EDIT:**

Based on @Clay's self-answer... so there is no parameter specified for the output, rather one simply does this: `OracleDataReader odr = cmd.ExecuteReader();`

Comment: "Be careful with your parameter typing declaration" - meaning...?

Comment: There is a "Ref" but no "RefCursor". Replacing .Cursor with .Ref made no difference (same err msg).

Comment: The DotConnect examples I've seen are all about using a DataAdapter, filling it, and then supplying a grid with that data. I'm beginning to think I'm going to have to do something like that, and then traverse the Dataset (which middleman I shouldn't need) to populate my List of String...arghhhh